# How to regex a url to redirect user

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, regular-expression

Using the regex and the `.htaccess` file, I want to redirect users to a certain URL.

*I want to redirect:*

- `http://www.example.com/*` but not `http://www.example.com/CDadmin/*`

*I have tried the following:*

- `http://www.example.com/CDadmin\/[*-^$CDadmin\/*]`

But does not work when I test with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cU5lC2/592).

Comment: Where are you wanting to redirect to? Is `/CDadmin` a physical directory on the filesystem? This would seem to only require a very simple regex - in fact it might not even require _much of_ a regex at all. Doing this redirect in Apache config (ie. .htaccess) will be much more efficient (and easier) than using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've not clarified the specifics of your question, I'll make some assumptions:

- You wish to redirect to a different domain. eg. `example.net`
- `example.net` points to a different server.
- `/CDadmin` is a physical directory on the filesystem.

---

1. At the top of the `.htaccess` file in the document root of `example.com`, place the following:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule (.*) http://example.net/$1 [R=302,L]
   ```

   The only regex here is `(.*)` - which will basically redirect *everything*. *(Read on...)*

   This is a temporary (`302`) redirect. Change to a `301` if you want to make it permanent.
2. Then, in the `.htaccess` file in the `/CDadmin` subdirectory, simply enable the rewrite engine:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   ```

   This will effectively override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file, so nothing will be redirected when accessing `/CDadmin/<something>`.